Looping macro in KaTex/GitLab README.md
I feel very silly for asking such a simple question but I'm trying to define a macro which can be used in a GitLab README.md which would be called like \foo{1,2,3}{4,5,6} and result in: {1 \atop \fbox{4}}\!\!{2 \atop \fbox{5}}\!\!{3 \atop \fbox{6}}
i.e. something like 
I've heard about \foreach, but I can't figure out how to use it. Would love an explanation or to be directed to a convenient resource so I can learn this myself.

those exclamation points aren't supposed to be there... clearly I've got a lot to learn.

welcome! .md means the file is markdown. that's nothing to do with TeX, so this question probably belongs on another site.

Oh! Sorry if I wasn't clear. Sites like GitHub and GitLab can process a type of TeX in their documentation files, which have a .md extension and is where I'm trying to use it. And thanks for the welcome!

[tag:katex] questions like this one are usually off-topic. See the tag description for more information.

katex and mathjax do not use tex: they are javascript libraries that emulate a portion of the math syntax of latex, but not the general text programming, or document structure.  also mathjax understands \! but you may need to protect the \  from the markdown processor, so \\! might work it depends...
